# Using は or が instead of を cases

Tags: usage

In a visual novel I ran into this sentence

嘉音くんの死亡は赤で宣言済みならば、生きているわけがない。よって、襲われた彼らが、嘉音くんと誤認するような何者かの変装の可能性がある！」

Which according to an official translation it means

"If Kanon's death was proclaimed with the red there's no way he was alive. Therefore there is a chance that the one who attacked the group was in a disguise to make the group mistake them for Kanon"

Is the が in 襲われた彼らが used as replacement for を

If so then why

I saw cases like 君は私が守る (Ill protect you) where the は seems to act as a replacement to を.

Based on what and why do you  use は or が instead of を. Is this mainly used when referring to organic things.

However I also saw cases like this

瞬発力が要求される無酸素運動に関しては定評があり (There is a established opinion in aerobic exercises where instantaneous force is required)
where the が is used instead of を. (and in this case が isn't used for an organic thing)

Can someone help me ?

Comment: It pretty much depends on what you want to say next. が marks the subject which is here 彼ら. Oh, and I approve the Visual Novel you're reading! :D

Comment: [無酸素運動] is "anaerobic exercise(s)".  During exercise with adequate fuel and oxygen (i.e., aerobic), muscle cells can contract repeatedly without fatigue.  During anaerobic or non-oxygen conditions (i.e., higher intensity exercise), muscle cells must rely on other reactions that do not require oxygen to fuel muscle contraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the choice of particles depends on the choice of predicate and here the predicate is altered through the translation. 
In Japanese, the subject (襲った何者か) is omitted, and 襲われた彼らが嘉音くんと誤認するような何者かの変装（である） is the predicate (here, である is altered with の in order to come before another nominal predicate 可能性がある. It would be easier for learners written ～の変装である可能性がある. They say the same thing.). For easier understanding, break down the complex predicate. The core of the predicate is 変装である=in disguise. 襲われた彼らが嘉音くんと誤認するような is a modifier for 変装: in disguise because of which the attacked group would have mistake (him) for Kanon (I'm not sure of my English whether I should say "because of which", "by which", "for which", "due to which", or something).
The translation use the causative verb which the Japanese one doesn't use. If you turn the translated sentence back into Japanese word by word, 襲われた彼らに（襲った彼を）を嘉音くんと誤認させる変装の可能性がある.

Answer (score 0):

No, if it was 襲われた彼らを花音くんと誤解する, the translation would be "(there's a chance that) someone/some people was/were in a disguise to make you mistake the ones who were attacked (plural) as Kanon-kun (singular)".

As for 瞬発力 が/を 要求される, either will do, and this has nothing to do with the problem above.